# I would think you can pipe the variable to the function

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

The following works fine, however, would it work piping it to the method instead of using semicolons?

```
function Main {
    
    $dev=@{Name='DEV'; DbServer='DEV'}; UpdateSspAppUserPassword @dev
    $uat=@{Name='UAT'; DbServer='UAT'}; UpdateSspAppUserPassword @uat
}

function UpdateSspAppUserPassword ($DbServer) {
    "hello world: $($DbServer)"
}
Clear-Host
Main
```

Output

```
hello world: DEV
hello world: UAT
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're ok using `[pscustomobject]` instead of hash tables then you can have your parameter take [`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument) and have your function leverage [pipeline processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3):

```
function Main {
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name='DEV'; DbServer='DEV' },
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name='UAT'; DbServer='UAT' } |
        UpdateSspAppUserPassword
}

function UpdateSspAppUserPassword {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string] $DbServer
    )

    process {
        "hello world: $($DbServer)"
    }
}

Main
```

Otherwise, using your current implementation, will require assistance from a loop making it less efficient since the function needs to be invoked as many elements are coming from pipeline:

```
function Main {
    @{ Name='DEV'; DbServer='DEV' }, @{ Name='UAT'; DbServer='UAT' } |
        ForEach-Object { UpdateSspAppUserPassword @_ }
}

function UpdateSspAppUserPassword ($DbServer) {
    "hello world: $($DbServer)"
}

Main
```

Comment: What's the advantages of the former with pscustomobject vs latter?

Comment: @Rod the latter will invoke the function as many elements are coming from the pipeline making it less efficient. The former leverages the pipeline in its full.

Comment: Nice idea: splatting the current item with `@_` 